# Cannot see installed user certificate

Tags: certificates

I have installed 2 user certificates to be used for wifi but when connecting the certificate is not showing up in the drop down . The CA certificate is showing though .

Comment: I am having the same problem. Did you find a solution? On my phone, it just randomly stops showing in the dropdown, and I have to re-install it and it disappears again in a few daus/hours...